# How to check TLS certificate expiration date with Clojure?

Tags: clojure, openssl

Normally I check a server's certificate expiration using the `openssl` command, but I'm learning Clojure and would really like to figure out how to do this without calling a shell command if possible.

How would I replicate this functionality?

```
$ openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 < /dev/null ^ /dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'
Apr 17 09:15:00 2019 GMT
```

Comment: While a) not a direct answer to your question and b) a shameless self-plug, you may still find the code in https://github.com/acrolinx/java-https-tester interesting because it shows a few things you can do with HTTPS connections from Clojure. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to obtain and inspect server certificates in Clojure using Java APIs via [interop](https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop).

Assuming the server speaks HTTPS, the certificates can be retrieved from a [javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) instance once it is in the connected state. The connection is established by calling the `getInputStream` method and the `getServerCertifcates` method returns the server certificates as an array of [java.security.cert.X509Certificate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html). To get an `HttpsURLConnection` instance, we have to call the `openConnection` method on a `java.net.URL`. The method `getNotAfter` of `X509Certificate` returns the certificate expiration date.

In Clojure, it would look like this:

```
(ns foo.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(defn get-server-certs [from]
  (let [url (io/as-url from)
        conn (.openConnection url)]
    (with-open [_ (.getInputStream conn)]
      (.getServerCertificates conn))))

(.getNotAfter (first (get-server-certs "https://www.google.com")))
;;=> #inst "2019-04-17T09:15:00.000-00:00"
```

Comment: This is beautiful. I was going to spend half an hour working out how to force an interceptor into the underlying HTTPClient from clj-http. Sometimes all the useful abstraction people build just gets in the way! :-)

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there any way I could also extract the body returned from this request as well as the certificate? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [shell](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.shell/sh) to execute your command. For example:

```
user=> (use '[clojure.java.shell :only [sh]])

user=> (println (:out (sh "openssl" "s_client" "-connect" "google.com:443")))
```

Comment: He asks how to do the same WITHOUT calling shell.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like it to be portable and not have to rely on shell commands.